# Feasibility of poisonous soft bullet

Tags: internal-consistency, weapons, poisons

In my story there is a hitman who has at his disposal a slingshot bullet with the following characteristics:

- the bullet range is of the order of 10 - 50 meters
- it is soft, therefore on impact it splashes rather than piercing. The target would feel something like the (somehow energetic) droppings of some birds fell on him. Uncareful attempts to wipe it clean could actually spread the subastance and increase the area of contact.
- it kills by delivering, on contact with skin, a deadly (within minutes) toxin to its target.

The bullet is meant to be used (at least in my story) in locations where skin exposure is not a problem, like beaches or swimming pools in summer.

Would such a type of bullet be realistic with known toxins?

Comment: Paintball bullet with toxic instead of paint inside?

Comment: Paintball bullets do hurt on impact on bare skin...

Comment: yeah, so make the "skin" of the bullet thinner than what it is on a paintball

Comment: You will always have the problem of pain. Range of a bullet is mostly dominated by it's speed, since no matter how big or heavy the bullet is, it's accelerating with 9.81 m/s$^2$ to the surface. If you want it to have a range of multiple 10s of meters, it will hurt

Comment: I would appreciate if whoever gave the downvote also put some effort in commenting why...

Comment: Ok, I thought about it for a minute and came up with multiple chemicals that would easily do the trick. I will not tell you any of them just in case someone reads this and builds that weapon. Yes, it is very doable and easy as well. There is this (unwritten) rule that you do not actually tell how to commit crimes and this is a pretty serious one - murder. The substances always have rather dramatic names (I will make one up, they all sound like that): Horrible death. I will not tell you an actual name. Just make one up like that for your story.

Comment: Oh And one more thing: Look at that horrible james bond movie that came out recently. I do not remember the name (and I do not think it is worth googling it) - the villain says he was disfigured from HCN. This is of course not realistic, but HCN is something everyone knows and therefor isn't giving out new information to the public. If you want, take HCN since everybody knows it is a poison.

Comment: For anyone curious about the reticence to answer on the part of @Raditz_35, here's a [discussion](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1978/6986) we had a while ago about "dangerous" questions.

Comment: Bullet should be in 2 parts - front poison, back projectile.  When the poison hits, it spreads on the surface, then the projectile drags it into the body along with any other nasties that are on the clothing.  Alternatively front projectile to make the hole and back poison that just follows the projectile.

Comment: @Frostfyre, though I understand the concern my question doesn't ask "how to build it", but only if it is realistic

Comment: @L.Dutch I am less concerned with the "how to build it" aspect. This kind of stuff is easily available online and a sling shot is ancient. The realistic part is what bothers me. I've seen it before on stack exchange: Someone asks a question and in an hour or two someone gives him a list of chemicals. As stated above, I could give you that list and they are easily made at home. I personally would feel a lot less worried if your question was purely about how to build such a device/bullet,  but it is implicated that you ask what substance since you specified "known toxins".

Comment: All: the answer is “yes it's realistic” not “here is the recipe” so don’t be so upset in the comments!  Focus on the way of making the soft ball and handling it, not the chemical it contains.

Comment: Reminds me of the darts in Zootopia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be made, but only with a ballistic trajectory. As others point out, a straight path to the target can only be attained with a big deal of speed, and thus a highly energetic crash upon the target. It's going to hurt. If you want that distance without that much harm, you should point upwards and go for a parabollic shot. It makes for a much harder to aim weapon, but at least it's more probably mistaken as a bird's dejection.

Answer (score 7):

Shooting someone with a liquid will require your "bullet" to be encased in some plastic wrapping. With a range of 10-50 meters, this seems a lot like a paintball gun (maybe a bit more powerful than regular ones). While it is totally okay to fill it with some poison killing on contact with the skin ([VX nerve agent](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/02/23/world/asia/kim-jong-nam-vx-nerve-agent-.html) comes to my mind), it certainly won't "feel something like the (somehow energetic) droppings of some birds fell on him", unless "somehow energetic" means a big ouch that can leave an [ecchymosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecchymosis).

So you can have that kind of gun, with a potent poison (only not killing too fast, from 10 to 15 minutes with VX), but your target will definitely know he has been shot, and not by a giant bird.

---

*Addressing some of the comments :*

**About the gun :** could be a slingshot as well, the speed will stay the same for a given range.

**About the bullet :** plastic encased liquid, wet paper with lead ball... doesn't matter as long as it is dense enough to overcome air resistance to a certain extent, and quite sturdy : a cotton-encased lead ball wouldn't work well since the cotton would deform and increase air resistance as well as randomize the flight path. All of the solutions that fulfil these requirements are equally good, but will nonetheless cause a "ouch" on impact.

Comment: I see your point. Please mind I specified it is a slingshot bullet, not a gun bullet.

Comment: @L.Dutch the form of acceleration does not matter. To get a range of up to 50 m, your bullet has to have a certain speed (even at impact so it "explodes"). Doesn't matter how you gain that speed, you need it.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason for the poison being encased in something. A small "bullet" made out of paper (or any liquid absorbing material) could do the trick given the right chemicals. It might even stick to the skin. The margin or error would be much smaller as well since it doesn't need to burst

Comment: @Raditz_35 a liquid incased in a piece of paper would probably not stay together for a flight path of up to 50 m

Comment: @Fl.pf. Not piece of paper formed into a ball, paper

Comment: @Raditz_35 doesn't matter, when it's so light it needs to be very fast to overcome air resistance, so it would hurt again

Comment: @Fl.pf. Put a lead ball (lead shot) in the middle. You just need your parts that touch the skin to be wet with death. Also the plastic wrapping wouldn't help at all in this case

Comment: @Fl.pf. Milk cartons and similar are typically made of what is basically sturdy paper. I wouldn't be surprised if the process could be adjusted to give (at least something very similar to) the effect the OP is after, especially if the properties of the encased chemicals can be chosen to match.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling would still hurt on impact

Comment: @Fl.pf. True, but it might well hold together for a 50 meters flight path.

Comment: Plastic encased liquid, wet paper with lead ball... doesn't matter as long as it is dense enough to overcome air resistance to a certain extent, and quite sturdy : a cotton-encased lead ball wouldn't work well since the cotton would deform and increase air resistance as well as randomize the flight path. All of the solutions that fulfill these requirements are equally good, but will nonetheless cause a "ouch" on impact.

Comment: @Keelhaul I think it matters a lot. Having your bullets burst when hitting the target might be the key design flaw of this gun.

Comment: @Raditz_35 Maybe, I'm not a fluid dynamics expert. But when I'm shot by a paintball bullet, I'm still marked by a fair amount of paint, whereas wet paper/cotton might retain most of the fluid.

Comment: How about a small lead ball encased in sponge? The sponge would deform less and cause (less) flight path randomization, but would be both liquid and impact absorbent, and, when full of a liquid toxin, the impact absorption would rapidly squeeze all the toxin out at the impact site.

Answer (score 5):

I think I have exactly what you need : a bullet made of frozen toxin. It was used by the CIA for Targeted Assassinations by Induced Heart Attack.

The dart from this secret CIA weapon can penetrate clothing and leave nothing but a tiny red dot on the skin. On penetration of the deadly dart, the individual targeted for assassination may feel as if bitten by a mosquito, or they may not feel anything at all. The poisonous dart completely disintegrates upon entering the target. The lethal poison then rapidly enters the bloodstream causing a heart attack. Once the damage is done, the poison denatures quickly, so that an autopsy is very unlikely to detect that the heart attack resulted from anything other than natural causes.

More reading: http://www.globalresearch.ca/cia-targeted-assassinations-by-induced-heart-attack-and-cancer/5326382

EDIT: I am not claiming that this weapon really existed, but whether or not this is true, it does fit the question. Here is a topic about it on reddit : https://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/45vsg1/til_cia_created_a_gun_that_could_shoot_darts_that/

Comment: Tbo, I think your answer would be more legitimate without the links. But thanks for making my day

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible.

A projectile that splashes so easily, is nearly impossible to accelerate to the necessary speed to travel up to 50 meters. The projectile would (most of the time) splatter while shooting, risking the life of the assasin.

Comment: It might be possible using some sort of sabot... but not very practical.

Answer (score 2):

This weapon you're proposing would definitely work - if you had removed the requirement for it to not hurt.

Potato guns have ranges that vary based on the method of propulsion used, but combustion and pneumatic both attain ranges that surpass your 50m requirement.

Here's how it would work though; you'd simply need some sort of potato gun as a base, and shoot sponges soaked in [VX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VX_(nerve_agent)), or some other suitable liquid toxin.

This hitman would be able to carry what looks essentially like a toy, fire off several dangerous sponges, and then leave.

As a bonus, VX evaporates into dangerous vapor, allowing the hitman to kill multiple targets alongside his main target; as such, hiding his true target.

Comment: You could just throw a Nerf toy.  The Nerf Vortex can go 100 yards.

Comment: @Will Like I said; The weapon would definitely work. I don't know if the toy you mentioned hurts when you hit with it, but it's very easy to get something large and soft to fly 50 meters.